# How to ask user to input an image in Pyqt5

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5

Hy! I made a simple GUI in Pyqt5. For the time being I am trying to make a GUI where the user can first input their info such as name, email address and I am trying to add an option to add their profile image. So I want to use an input from the user that is a image, store it and use it later in the app. Is that even possible?

Thanks to anyone in advance!

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to do this. Widgets support drag and drop; you can implement drag enter and drop events. Or you can open a file directory and browse for a photo. Here is an example showing both methods:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

class PhotoLabel(QLabel):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.setText('\n\n Drop Image Here \n\n')
        self.setStyleSheet('''
        QLabel {
            border: 4px dashed #aaa;
        }''')

    def setPixmap(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().setPixmap(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setStyleSheet('''
        QLabel {
            border: none;
        }''')


class Template(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.photo = PhotoLabel()
        btn = QPushButton('Browse')
        btn.clicked.connect(self.open_image)
        grid = QGridLayout(self)
        grid.addWidget(btn, 0, 0, Qt.AlignHCenter)
        grid.addWidget(self.photo, 1, 0)
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.resize(300, 200)

    def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasImage:
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()

    def dragMoveEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasImage:
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasImage:
            event.setDropAction(Qt.CopyAction)
            filename = event.mimeData().urls()[0].toLocalFile()
            event.accept()
            self.open_image(filename)
        else:
            event.ignore()

    def open_image(self, filename=None):
        if not filename:
            filename, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Select Photo', QDir.currentPath(), 'Images (*.png *.jpg)')
            if not filename:
                return
        self.photo.setPixmap(QPixmap(filename))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    gui = Template()
    gui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```